# Neither mathematica nor rubi can solve definite Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Before I begin I would like to point out that I am very new to Mathematica so please excuse my dumbness.
I am trying to find a solution to the following Integrals:

1. Integrand Function:

```
rpop[rho_, R_, alpha_, yp0_, yp_] := R*((rho - R*Sin[alpha])^2 + (R*Cos[alpha])^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)^(-(1/2));
```

2. Mathematica is able to integrate it with respect to alpha:

```
Intalpha[rho_, R_, yp0_, yp_] := 
      Assuming[Element[{R, rho, yp0, yp}, Reals] && R > 0 && rho > 0, 
       Integrate[rpop[rho, R, alpha, yp0, yp], {alpha, 0, 2*Pi}]];
```

giving the following solution:

```
(2 R (Sqrt[1 + (2 R rho)/(R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]EllipticK[-((4 R rho)/(R^2 - 2 R rho + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2))] + Sqrt[1 - (2 R rho)/(R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]EllipticK[(4 R rho)/(R^2 + 2 R rho + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]))
/Sqrt[((R^2 - 2 R rho + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2) (R^2 + 2 R rho + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2))/(R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]
```

3. Now I want to Integrate the above result with respect to the variable yp0 between points a and -a (a for now is just a parameter). Mathematica is not giving any result (not even when I tried to compute a `Series` in a=0 of the unsolved integral). I also tried to use rubi's `Int` and it is giving me the following solution:

```
ProvaInt[rho_, R_, yp_, a_] := Int[Intalpha[rho, R, yp0, yp], {yp0, -a, a}]

ProvaInt[rho, R, yp, a]

-\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(yp0 \[Rule] \(-a\)\)]\) (-((
      2 R Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]
        Sqrt[((R + rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)/(
       R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]
        Subst[Int[(
         Sqrt[R^2 + 2 R rho + rho^2 + yp0^2]
           EllipticK[-((4 R rho)/((R - rho)^2 + yp0^2))])/(
         Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2] Sqrt[
          rho^2 + yp0^2 + R^2 (1 - (4 rho^2)/(R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2))]),
          yp0], yp0, yp - yp0])/Sqrt[(R + rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]) - (
     2 R Sqrt[((R - rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)/(
      R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)] Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]
       Subst[Int[(
        Sqrt[R^2 - 2 R rho + rho^2 + yp0^2]
          EllipticK[(4 R rho)/((R + rho)^2 + yp0^2)])/(
        Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2] Sqrt[
         rho^2 + yp0^2 + R^2 (1 - (4 rho^2)/(R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2))]), 
        yp0], yp0, yp - yp0])/Sqrt[(R - rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]) + 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(yp0 \[Rule] 
    a\)]\) (-((
     2 R Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]
       Sqrt[((R + rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)/(R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)]
       Subst[
       Int[(Sqrt[R^2 + 2 R rho + rho^2 + yp0^2]
          EllipticK[-((4 R rho)/((R - rho)^2 + yp0^2))])/(
        Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2] Sqrt[
         rho^2 + yp0^2 + R^2 (1 - (4 rho^2)/(R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2))]), 
        yp0], yp0, yp - yp0])/Sqrt[(R + rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]) - (
    2 R Sqrt[((R - rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)/(
     R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2)] Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + (yp - yp0)^2]
      Subst[Int[(
       Sqrt[R^2 - 2 R rho + rho^2 + yp0^2]
         EllipticK[(4 R rho)/((R + rho)^2 + yp0^2)])/(
       Sqrt[R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2] Sqrt[
        rho^2 + yp0^2 + R^2 (1 - (4 rho^2)/(R^2 + rho^2 + yp0^2))]), 
       yp0], yp0, yp - yp0])/Sqrt[(R - rho)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2])
```

and for what i understand of rubi (not much), when Subst appears in the solution it means it's missing the rule to compute the Integral.

4. To complete the model I would also have to Integrate the solution of this (for now) unsolved integral with respect to the variable yp.

Does anyone know how I can find a solution to this kind of Integrals?
If no, is there any way you think I will be able to find a good approximated solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can get an answer for Integrate[EllipticK[-a/x^2], x], but as soon as you start to put anything in the denominator it ceases to be able to integrate. For example, Integrate[EllipticK[-a/(1 + x^2)], x] does not give an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: It might be useful to give a references as to where this integral arises. The integrand can be expanded into Legendre polynomials, via its generating function, which may help you somewhat.

Comment: @TheDoctor I have posted another question regarding this problem (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220336/cant-find-a-way-to-numerically-evaluate-integral-with-singularity). I am trying to evaluate magnetic energy, via vector potential method, for the geometry explained in the other question. Your answer is very interesting but i don't know anything about Legendre polynomials, fell free to expand!!

Comment: @gabrielecolombo: The 1/r quantity you are integrating is (proportional to) the magnetic field, *not* to the vector potential. For concentric cylinders I'm not convinced that the integral you are trying to compute corresponds to the physics of the problem.

Your cylindrical regions are of finite length, so I assume that you are using the approximate field (or vector potential) for the infinite-length case in your calculation? 

Have a look at the following article, which may be relevant:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/37/5/055203

Comment: @TheDoctor Referring to the link you provided, I am using equation (8) with (|r-r'|/c)==0. The first surface integral is proportional to the vector potential generated by the cylinder and the second integrates that potential over a second cylindrical surface to find one of the contributions to the system's magnetic energy. The length of each cylinder is given by the difference of integration extremes regarding y-coordinate.