# Can't find a way to numerically evaluate integral with singularity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, singularity

Consider this function:
$$f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_p-x_{p0})^2+(y_p-y_{p0})^2+(z_p-z_{p0})^2}}$$
I need to integrate this function over the cylindrical surface $S_1$ containing point $(x_{p0},y_{p0},z_{p0})$ and then integrate the result over a second cylindrical surface $S_2$ containing point $(x_{p},y_{p},z_{p})$:
$$\int_{S_2}\int_{S_{1}}f\ dS_{p0}\ dS_p$$
The two cylindrical surfaces must be coaxial (y-axes). I used the following parametrizations:
$$(x_{p0},y_{p0},z_{p0})\rightarrow (r_1 cos(\alpha),y_{p0},r_1 sin(\alpha)),\quad y_{p0}\in [a_1,b_1]$$
$$(x_{p},y_{p},z_{p})\rightarrow (r_2 cos(\beta),y_{p},r_2 sin(\beta)),\quad y_{p}\in [a_2,b_2]$$
Assuming the system is symmetrical, the result of the first integral will be the same for all values of $\beta$ so I'll just assume $\beta=0$ and multiply for $2\pi$. The integral becomes
$$\int_{a_2}^{b_2}\int_{a_1}^{b_1}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2\pi\ r_1\ r_2}{\sqrt{(r_1 cos(\alpha)-r2)^2+(y_p-y_{p0})^2+(r_1 sin(\alpha))^2}}\ d\alpha\ dy_{p0}\ dy_p$$ (since $2\pi r_1 r_2$ is a constant respect to the integration variables I don't consider it in further calculations).
I've tried to solve this in different ways:

1.`Integrate` won't do the job: mathematica can integrate the function with respect to $\alpha$ but it is unable to integrate the result.

2. To try overcome this issue I tried expanding in series the result of $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f d\alpha$. Here is the code:

   f[r1_, r2_, [Alpha]*, yp0*, yp_] = 
     1/(Sqrt[(r1 - r2 Cos[[Alpha]])^2 + (r1 Sin[[Alpha]])^2 + (yp - 
            yp0)^2]);

   integrale1[r1_, r2_, yp0_, yp_] = 
    Assuming[Element[{r1, r2, yp0, yp}, Reals] && 
      r2 > 0 && r1 > 0 && (yp - yp0)^2 >= 0, 
     Integrate[2*f[r1, r2, [Alpha], yp0, yp], {[Alpha], 0, Pi}]]

   s1[r1_, r2_, yp0_, yp_] = 
     Assuming[Element[{r1, r2, yp0, yp}, Reals] && 
       r1 > 0 && r2 > 0, 
      Normal[Series[integrale1[r1, r2, yp0, yp], {yp0, 0, 3}]]];

the problem with this approach is that the error becomes incredibly high for close values of `r1` and `r2` and for close values of `yp0` and `yp`

```
erroreAss[r1_, r2_, yp0_, yp_] = 
  Abs[integrale1[r1, r2, yp0, yp] - s1[r1,r2, yp0, yp]];
```

`erroreAss`is the function I use to evaluate the error committed when expanding in series.

3.Since I wasn't lucky with these symbolic methods I am now trying numerical integration. Here is the code:

```
mu0 = N[(10^-7)/(4 *Pi), 100];

S1 = ({xp0, yp0, zp0} -> {r1 Cos[\[Alpha]], yp0, r1 Sin[\[Alpha]]});

S2 = ({xp, yp, zp} -> {r2 , yp, 0});
f = 1/Sqrt[(xp - xp0)^2 + (yp - yp0)^2 + (zp - zp0)^2];
F[r1_, r2_, \[Alpha]_, yp0_, yp_] = (f /. Thread[S1]) /. Thread[S2];

intA[r1_, r2_, yp0_, yp_] = 
 Assuming[Element[{r1, r2, yp0, yp}, Reals] && r1 > 0 && r2 > 0, 
  Integrate[F[r1, r2, \[Alpha], yp0, yp], {\[Alpha], -Pi, 0, Pi}]];

M12[r1_?NumericQ, r2_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, 
   s_?NumericQ] := 
  Assuming[Element[{r1, r2, a1, a2, s}, Reals] && r1 > 0 && r2 > 0 && 
    s > 0, NIntegrate[ 
    2*mu0 intA[r1, r2, yp0, yp], {yp0, a1, a1 + s}, {yp, a2, a2 + s}, 
    Exclusions -> {yp == yp0}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
    MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 15]];
```

I think this method could actually work for my problem but I keep getting error messages.  When I try to evaluate this (so when the two surfaces correspond)

```
M12[1/100, 1/100, -1/1000, -1/1000, 2/1000]
```

Mathematic doesn't return any value (actually it did give results but when I switched to a fresh kernel it stopped, this was very confusing but I guess the values it gave me weren't so reliable in the end) and (in any case) shows error message `NIntegrate::slwcon`.
Instead when I try to evaluate this (in this case the two surfaces are separate)

```
M12[1/100, 1/100, -1/1000, +1/1000, 2/1000]
```

it just gives `0` as a result and error message `NIntegrate::izero`.

I've tried using higher values of Workingprecision (up to 100) and  MinRecursion (up to 80, I don't even know if it makes sense) and tried using a PrecisionGoal but nothing seems to change.

What am I missing ? Is there a specific method that should be used to evaluate this integral ?? Any help will be appreciated!!